# What is the formal way to use in a IT technical proposal "check, verify or validate''?

Tags: formality

What is the formal way to use in a IT technical proposal "check, verify or validate''? I'd like to use the word more formally.

Comment: What is wrong with the words you list?  Please edit your question to provide more context, a sense of what other solutions you have considered, and why these don't work for you.  The terms you list seem appropriately formal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to choose between these three words, and without knowing the specific context, I would recommend **validate**.

Generally speaking, in information technology you want to distinguish between *interpretive* actions performed by human beings, and *mechanical* or *computational* actions performed by machines.

In the example that comes to my mind, a program of some kind has received an input. However, before it proceeds with its calculation, it compares the received input with a range of values for which the calculation will have meaning, i.e. to the ultimate human user.

The program here is *validating* the data, since the value returned by the comparison is either *valid* or *not valid*.

In contrast, *check* and *verify* are higher level actions.  You can define what they mean in your proposal.  However, readers sometimes assume that a *check* or a *verification* means more than you really intended.